# Best Practice for unknwon Types for MongoDB Collections

Tags: c#, mongodb

For a reusable system I need to implement a connector to a mongoDB system and insert unknown types into the collection (and extract it later on). The data is provided as Json-string and I want to add meta-information fields and store the document in the MongoDB. I know, the documents will be different at runtime, but not too much (still, I do not know their definition in before).

I was first thinking about something like

```cs
public class DataWrapper
{
  public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
  public string InternalComment { get; set; }
  public object RAW { get; set; }   
}
```

And deserializing the json to dynamic or Newtonsoft.json.linq.JObject, assigning the result to the RAW property of the DataWrapper. The collection of MongoDB is casted to the DataWrapper type.

I am sure, I am not the first one thinking about this requirement, but could not find best practices on that so far.

Are there already documented best practices on this requirement or known flaws I am running into right now with the approach?

Comment: What about `BsonDocument`?

Comment: If you don't need to index on anything inside the data itself you may as well just store the Json *string* in the database rather than trying to represent it as an object.

Comment: @IanMercer At least the Timestamp will be indexed later in the project as there will come up sets of time series data

Comment: @John This looks promising - The first test results in errors on Collection insertion (Array not allowed on root level of BsonDocument) - I dive more into this issue.

Comment: Ah, you might want to use `BsonValue` then - both `BsonDocument` and `BsonArray` extend from `BsonValue`. I can't guarantee this won't present other issues with deserialization, of course :)

Comment: I finally used the BsonDocument, BsonArray and BsonValue in Combination. I now get recursive objects independent from compile-time classes and so far the performance of the Database looks fair. So maybe the solution was far more easy than I was expecting :-)